# as.alist.character?

Tags: r

I wish to create a call object from a string. `alist()`, which does more or less what I want in interactive (manual input) mode, doesn't seem to have coercion methods, nor does `as.call` do what I would hope.

Consider the following code,

```
string = "<<mychunk, cache=TRUE, fig.show=hold, dev=png, echo=c(1,3)>>="
sanitized = gsub("<<|>>=", "", string)
## as.call(sanitized)
## as.alist(sanitized)

as.alist.character <- function(x)
   eval(parse(text = paste("alist(", x, ")")))

as.alist.character(sanitized)
```

Now, `eval(parse)` is frowned upon in my (infernal) circles; can you suggest better?

Thanks.

Comment: define `ept <- function(text, ...) eval(parse(text = text, ...))`

Comment: @kohske that's cheeky ;)

Comment: then again, maybe it isn't *so bad* to use `eval(parse)` in such special circumstances.

Comment: Turning text into expressions is exactly what parse is designed for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just copying my own dirty solution here from [#142](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/142) which is pretty much equivalent to yours (and has the same issue about "infernal circles"):

```
x = 'label,a=1,b=asdf,c="qwer",d=FALSE,e=c(1,2,3)'
z = formals(eval(parse(text = sprintf('function(%s){}', x))))
str(z)
```

Let's see if there are other cleaner tricks.