# How to create an R function programmatically?

Tags: r, function

[Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) recently asked an interesting question on the [r-devel mailing](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-October/064946.html) list, and being unable to find an existing question on the topic on StackOverflow, I thought it might be useful for it exist here as well.

To paraphrase:

**An R function consists of three elements: an argument list, a body and an environment. Can we construct a function programmatically from these three elements?**

(A fairly comprehensive answer is reached at the end of the thread in the r-devel link above. I will leave this open for others to recreate the benchmarking of the various solutions themselves and supply it as an answer, but be sure to cite Hadley if you do. If no one steps up in a few hours I'll do it myself.)

Comment: I think this is why they invented lisps!

Comment: strange as it may sound, we've seen a case where one might want to [parse a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9345373/471093) to achieve something similar (knitr).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is an expansion on the discussion [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-October/064957.html).

Our three pieces need to be an argument list, a body and an environment.

For the environment, we will simply use `env = parent.frame()` by default.

We do not really want a regular old list for the arguments, so instead we use `alist`
which has some different behavior:

> "...values are not evaluated, and tagged arguments with no value are allowed"

```
args <- alist(a = 1, b = 2)
```

For the body, we `quote` our expression to get a `call`:

```
body <- quote(a + b)
```

One option is to convert `args` to a pairlist and then simply call the function `function` 
using `eval`:

```
make_function1 <- function(args, body, env = parent.frame()) {
      args <- as.pairlist(args)
      eval(call("function", args, body), env)
}
```

Another option is to create an empty function, and then fill it with the desired values:

```
make_function2 <- function(args, body, env = parent.frame()) {
      f <- function() {}
      formals(f) <- args
      body(f) <- body
      environment(f) <- env

      f
}
```

A third option is to simply use `as.function`:

```
make_function3 <- function(args, body, env = parent.frame()) {
      as.function(c(args, body), env)
}
```

And finally, this seems very similar to the first method to me, except
we are using a somewhat different idiom to create the function call, using
`substitute` rather than `call`:

```
make_function4 <- function(args, body, env = parent.frame()) {
      subs <- list(args = as.pairlist(args), body = body)
      eval(substitute(`function`(args, body), subs), env)
}


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
      make_function1(args, body),
      make_function2(args, body),
      make_function3(args, body),
      make_function4(args, body),
      function(a = 1, b = 2) a + b
    )

Unit: nanoseconds
                          expr   min      lq  median      uq    max
1 function(a = 1, b = 2) a + b   187   273.5   309.0   363.0    673
2   make_function1(args, body)  4123  4729.5  5236.0  5864.0  13449
3   make_function2(args, body) 50695 52296.0 53423.0 54782.5 147062
4   make_function3(args, body)  8427  8992.0  9618.5  9957.0  14857
5   make_function4(args, body)  5339  6089.5  6867.5  7301.5  55137
```

Comment: joran, great summary thanks. Would you comment on the benchmarking please? It looks from your result like function1 is marginally quicker than the other functions. But with the silly alternative: `  function(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8, i = 9, j = 10) {
    exp(a + b) * (c + d)^e / f - ln(g) + h^i^j
  }` I get that function4 appears much quicker than the other ones. Any thoughts?

Comment: extending `make_function1` in your code to never overwrite existing functions, I came up with the following: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/742#issuecomment-451592137

Answer (score 8):

`rlang` has a function called `new_function` that does this :

> **Usage**
>
> new_function(args, body, env = caller_env())

```
library(rlang)
g <- new_function(alist(x = ), quote(x + 3))
g
# function (x) 
# x + 3
```

Answer (score 7):

There is also the issue of creating `alist` objects programmatically as that can be useful for creating functions when the number of arguments is variable.

An `alist` is simply a named list of empty symbols. These empty symbols can be created with `substitute()`. So:

```
make_alist <- function(args) {
  res <- replicate(length(args), substitute())
  names(res) <- args
  res
}

identical(make_alist(letters[1:2]), alist(a=, b=))
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help, but below code might be beneficial in some scenarios,

**hello_world** can be the string which will be used to create function and assign will be used to name function **hello_world**

```
hello_world <- "print('Hello World')"

assign("Hello",function()
  {
    eval(parse(text = hello_world))
  }, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

This will create a function called hello_world