# R convert text field to function

Tags: r

I want to use information from a field and include it in a R function, e.g.:

```
data #name of the data.frame with only one raw

"(if(nclusters>0){OptmizationInputs[3,3]*beta[1]}else{0})" # this is the raw
```

If I want to use this information inside a function how could I do it?

```
Another example:
A=c('x^2')
B=function (x) A
B(2)
"x^2"  # this is the return. I would like to have the return something like 2^2=4.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `body<-` and parse

```
A <- 'x^2'

B <- function(x) {}

body(B) <- parse(text = A)

B(3)
## [1] 9
```

There are more ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982528/how-to-create-an-r-function-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `plyr`:

```
A <- 'x^2'
library(plyr)
body(B) <- as.quoted(A)[[1]]
> B(5)
[1] 25
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A  <- "x^2"; x <- 2
BB <- function(z){ print( as.expression(do.call("substitute", 
                                            list( parse(text=A)[[1]], list(x=eval(x) ) )))[[1]] ); 
               cat( "is equal to ", eval(parse(text=A)))
              }
 BB(2)
#2^2
#is equal to  4
```

Managing expressions in R is very weird. `substitute` refuses to evaluate its first argument so you need to use `do.call` to allow the evaluation to occur before the substitution. Furthermore the printed representation of the expressions hides their underlying representation. Try removing the  fairly cryptic (to my way of thinking) `[[1]]` after the `as.expression(.)` result.