# Return statement in expression to be used as function body

Tags: r

I run lots of heavy computations in R, and I am trying to write a function that would help me cache my results and only compute them if necessary. I came up with this:

```
memoize <- function(filename, fun, ...){
    if(file.exists(filename)){
        message(paste("Reading", filename))
        return(readRDS(filename))
    } else {
        message(paste(filename, "not found, running computations"))
        result <- do.call(fun, list(...))
        message(paste("Writing", filename))
        saveRDS(result, filename)
        return(result)
    }
}
```

which allows me to do:

```
result <- memoize("test.rds", function(){ return(runif(100))} )
```

This works just fine, however, I want to be able to do without the "function()" part, i.e. pass an expression instead of a function. This can be done as follows:

```
memoize <- function(filename, expr){
    if(file.exists(filename)){
        message(paste("Reading", filename))
        return(readRDS(filename))
    } else {
        message(paste(filename, "not found, running computations"))
    
         f <- function(){}
        body(f) <- expr
        environment(f) <- parent.frame()
        result <- do.call(f, list())
    
        message(paste("Writing", filename))
        saveRDS(result, filename)
        return(result)
    }
}
```

as per [capturing an expression as a function body in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495708/capturing-an-expression-as-a-function-body-in-r)

This works fine when using

```
result <- memoize("test.rds", { runif(100)} )
```

However, I would like to keep the explicit return() statements in that expression. When I try

```
result <- memoize("test.rds", { return(runif(100))} )
```

I get

> no function to return from, jumping to top level

I clearly misunderstand how this works: why does expr seem to be evaluated before being bound to f? And how could I achieve this?

Comment: Fundamentally, [adding `return` statements everywhere in R doesn’t make sense to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968).

Comment: I am well aware of this, but this is a matter of personal preference and clearly a key part of the question.

Comment: I think the [`memoise`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html) package might be an in-place substitute for this, and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of [my recommendation *not* to use `return` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968) except when early access is explicitly required, the following should work:

```
memoize = function (cache_filename, expr) {
    if (file.exists(cache_filename)) {
        message('reading ', cache_filename)
        readRDS(cache_filename)
    } else {
        message(cache_filename, ' not found, rerunning computation')
        f = local(function () NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv)
        body(f) = substitute(expr)
        result = f()
        saveRDS(result, cache_filename)
        result
    }
}
```

Note in particular that using `do.call(f, list())` isn’t necessary and doesn’t really make sense: it’s a regular function, just call it using `f()`.

What your current solution does is actually quite interesting: it evaluates `expr` at the point of use and assigns the *result* to the function body of `f`. In fact, this only happens to work when the result is a simple R value, not when it’s a complex object. And in that case you don’t need the nested function at all, you can evaluate `expr` on its own, and this is in fact a fairly common pattern (used, for example, in the implementations of `try` and `tryCatch`!). In other words, the following would be an idiomatic implementation (but doesn’t support using control flow such as `return()`:

```
memoize = function (cache_filename, expr) {
    if (file.exists(cache_filename)) {
        message('reading ', cache_filename)
        readRDS(cache_filename)
    } else {
        message(cache_filename, ' not found, rerunning computation')
        result = expr
        saveRDS(result, cache_filename)
        result
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick answer! :-)