# R - Evaluate a nested function in an environment

Tags: r, function, eval

I am trying to run a chunk of R code in a sandbox-ed fashion, by loading all the necessary dependencies (functions and data) into a new environment and evaluating an expression within that environment. However, I'm running into trouble with functions calling other functions in the environment. Here's a simple example:

```
jobenv <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
assign("f1", function(x) x*2, envir=jobenv)
assign("f2", function(y) f1(y) + 1, envir=jobenv)
expr <- quote(f2(3))
```

Using `eval` on `expr` fails since `f2` can't find `f1`

```
> eval(expr, envir=jobenv)
Error in f2(3) : could not find function "f1"
```

whereas explicitly attaching the environment works

```
> attach(jobenv)
> eval(expr)
[1] 7
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I couldn't find any permutation of the `eval` call that works. Is there a way to get the same effect without attaching the environment?

Comment: You should make your edit a new question, since it's very different than your original one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did, here it is: [R - evaluate nested function call in a deserialized environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733323/r-evaluate-nested-function-call-in-a-deserialized-environment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this, but I kind of like this one:

```
jobenv <- new.env(parent=globalenv())

local({
    f1 <- function(x) x*2
    f2 <- function(y) f1(y) + 1
}, envir=jobenv)

## Check that it works
ls(jobenv)
# [1] "f1" "f2"
local(f2(3), envir=jobenv)
# [1] 7
eval(quote(f2(3)), envir=jobenv)
# [1] 7
```

Comment: +1 very nice. Though you could shorten it and make it more general by putting both the function definitions inside one `local` call.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - Good point. Thanks. (Edited my answer to incorporate your suggestion.)

Answer (score 6):

Scope is defined when the function is created, not when it's called.  See [section 10.7 of the Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope) manual.

This seems a bit odd to me, but you get the same behavior even if you avoid `assign` all together and just use `$<-`.

```
jobenv <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
jobenv$f1 <- function(x) x*2
jobenv$f2 <- function(y) f1(y) + 1
expr <- quote(f2(3))
eval(expr, envir=jobenv)
```

This seems to be because the enclosing environment of `f1` and `f2` is the global environment.  I would have expected it to be `jobenv`.

```
> environment(jobenv$f1)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> environment(jobenv$f2)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

One solution is to explicitly set the environment of each function... but there has to be an easier way.

```
> environment(jobenv$f1) <- jobenv
> environment(jobenv$f2) <- jobenv
> eval(expr, envir=jobenv)
[1] 7
```

Comment: +1 for `inherits=TRUE`. I have to confess, though, I don't see how the variable `"f1"` is found in `jobenv` before it is first assigned there. From the quoted passage, I'd expect the symbol, not being encountered there, to be assigned into the user's workspace.

Comment: Looks like I was right to be skeptical: your first example just assigns `f1`and `f2` into the global environment. (Try `ls()` and `ls(jobenv)` after running it.) And your second example doesn't work either.

Comment: Try (as one solution) `eval(quote(f1 <- function(x) x*2), envir=jobenv)` and `eval(quote(f2 <- function(y) f1(y) + 1), envir=jobenv)`. The key is that the assignments (whether executed by `eval` or `do.call` or whatever) need to be, themselves, evaluated within `jobenv`. Or, I guess, use any of the approaches in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982528/how-to-create-an-r-function-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the comments. I edited my question to clarify the intended result.