# Return a function's code

Tags: r, parsing, shiny

This would seem to be an elementary question, but I can't seem to find an answer on stackoverflow.

How can I obtain the following effect:

```
f <- function(x = 1){x^2}
miracle(f)
[1]  "x^2"
```

The context is a shiny app (package by RStudio) in which I have a `textInput()` function to which I supply an initial value `x^2`. While this works:

```
textInput(inputId = "inFun", label = h4("Enter a function:"), value = "x^2")
```

this doesn't:

```
textInput(inputId = "inFun", label = h4("Enter a function:"), value = f)
```

It appears that I need something like "x^2" on the rhs of value.

Below is a representative sample of several variations I have tried:

```
eval(parse(text = f))
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

f(x = "x")
Error in x^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

`f`
function(x){x^2}

f(x = `x`)
Error in f(x = x) : object 'x' not found
```

Is there a built-in function for this?

Comment: What about `body(f)`?

Comment: Can you adjust the title? Without putting the answer in the title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question, based on Roman Luštrik's comment, to invite suggestions for improvements rather than raising my meagre tally of "points".

Roman suggested the function body(), which I had never heard of. Here is what `body()` does to `f`:

```
f <- function(x = 1){x^2}

> body(f)
{
    x^2
}
```

The curly brackets were unwanted, so I searched a little further. I managed to get rid of the curly brackets with this:

```
> gsub(' {2,}','',deparse(body(f))[2])
[1] "x^2"
```

The above, therefore, answers my own question. But is there a more elegant and shorter way?

Following Roman's suggestion to use `body()`, I came across this outstanding answer by joran, hadley, and several others, which provided me with a template:

[How to create an R function programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982528/how-to-create-an-r-function-programmatically)

There it explains how to create a function programmatically from an argument list, a body and an environment. I therefore decided to construct my function `f` with these 3 primitives and to call the body from inside shiny's `textInput`.

So I put this in my `global.R` file (the small-cap `g` is shorthand for global)

```
# Convenience function
make.function <- function(args = alist(a = 1, b = 2), body = quote(a + b), 
                          env = parent.frame()) {
  subs <- list(args = as.pairlist(args), body = body)
  eval(substitute(`function`(args, body), subs), env)
}
gArg <- alist(a = 1, b = 2)
gBody <- quote(a + b)
gFun <- make.function(gArg, gBody)
```

Then in my `server.R` file, I have:

```
textInput(inputId = "inFun", label = h4("1. Enter a function:"), 
          value = deparse(body(gFun)))
```

And it works!

I was planning to write `value = gBody` or something to that effect, but my first success came with `deparse(body(gFun))`, so that's what I'm using now.

The use of `make.function` to produce a 'static' function in `global.R` is of course overkill, but I'm using `make.function` elsewhere inside `server.R` to process the user-supplied arguments and body to create new functions and plot them, so it's a very useful function to have.

Thanks Roman: if you write your own answer I'll accept yours.