# R : Define a function from character string

Tags: r

I'd  like to define a function `f` from parameters and an expression that are `character` strings read from a `.csv` file.
This function `f` has the following expression :

```
f = function( parameters ) { expression }
```

where parameters are a list of n parameters and the expression is a function of these parameters.
For example: the parameters are `x1`,`x2`,`x3`, and expression is `(x1+x2)*x3`.
The function `f` is then `f = function(x1,x2,x3){ (x1+x2)*x3 }`.
How I proceed in R to define such functions ?

#### EDIT add more context:

Given 2 charcaters strings , for body and arguments

```
body="(x1+x2)*x3"
args = "x1,x2,x3"
```

How we can get ?:

```
function (x1, x2, x3) 
(x1 + x2) * x3
```

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982528/how-to-create-an-r-function-programmatically) is similar but don't answer exactly this one, since the solution proposed don't create the function formals (arguments) from a character string.

Comment: What have you tried already? What specific problem are you getting stuck on? If you need to learn the basics of coding, this isn't the place. If you have a specific issue in translating this problem into code, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Have a look at the examples in `?as.function`.  It's not quite the same, but might be interesting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`eval()` and `parse()`, used together, may help you do what you want:

```
body <- "(x1 + x2) * x3"
args <- "x1, x2, x3"

eval(parse(text = paste('f <- function(', args, ') { return(' , body , ')}', sep='')))
# Text it:
f(3,2,5)
## 10
```

**The explanation:** [`parse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/parse.html) will return the parsed, but unevaluated, expression. I use the `text` argument in the function to pass a string to the parser. [`eval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) will evaluate the parsed expression (in this case, it will execute the code block you've just parsed).

Hope this helps