# Functions returning functions - substituting in parameters

Tags: r

If have a function that returns a function:

```
makeFunction <- function (d) {
    function (x) { x/d }
}

f <- makeFunction(2)
print(f)
# function (x) { x/d }
# <environment: 0x34216b8>
f(4) # 2, as expected
```

What I want is to have `f` simply "be" `function (x) { x/2 }`. By "be", I mean that it doesn't carry that environment around (with the value of `d` in it), and when I `print` it, it shows `function (x) { x/2 }`.
Is such a thing possible?

---

#### Attempts so far

I can get almost there with `substitute`:

```
makeFunction.sub <- function (d) {
    substitute(function (x) { x/d }, list(d=d))
}
g <- makeFunction.sub(2)
print(g)
# function(x) {
#     x/2
# }
```

However, `g` is not a function - it's a call. So to get the function I need to `eval` it. But then it loses the 2 and reverts to `d`:

```
eval(g)
# function (x) { x/d }
```

Is there any way I can make the returned function forget about `d` and just substitute 2 directly?

(In practice, I don't mind carrying around the environment, but I was just curious...)

---

#### Solution

Going to mark as dupe (well, subset) of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982528/how-to-create-an-r-function-programmatically/12983961#12983961) (thanks @joran).

That question & answer are much more detailed, so for the record:

```
makeFunction <- function (d) {
    of <- function (x) {}
    # do the substitution of d in the body
    body(of) <- substitute(x/d, list(d=d))
    # don't need to carry around the little local environment anymore
    environment(of) <- .GlobalEnv
    return(of)
}
h <- makeFunction(2)
print(h)
# function (x) 
# x/2
```

Comment: Is anything here useful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12983961/324364

Comment: ooo, probably! cheers, will have a read (my lack of knowledge makes it hard to do an intelligent search for these questions)

Comment: some good theory to read is here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures

Comment: and a helpful function beyond the link is `pryr::unenclose`. You can then do something like `f <- pryr::unenclose(makeFunction(2))`