# Call the R `function` function as an usual function

Tags: r, function, call

The R base package contains a function called `function`. Its help page tell us to call it as `function( arglist ) expr`. I can use this syntax, but I was wandering if it is possible to call it as most R functions, namely something like `FuncName( arg1, arg2 )`. In other terms is it possible to put `expr` within the parenthesis?
More explicitly, can I write  `` `function`( arglist, expr ) ``?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12982528/324364) might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you are asking, but `function` isn't really a function, it's a [special keyword](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/gram.c#L4029-L4058).

Comment: @joran Thanks. It shows that `args <- pairlist(a = 1, b = 2)` `body <- quote(a + b)` `myf <- eval( `function`(args, body) )` works. This is almost the answer (apart from the use of `eval`).

Comment: @nrussell Tanks. I didn't realize this.