# How to call the `function` function

Tags: r, function, primitive

in `R` pretty much everything that is not a variable of another type is a function.

It seems that `function` itself is one :

```
`function`
# .Primitive("function")
```

Though I'm not sure, it doesn't return the same thing as say `+` :

```
`+`
# function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("+")
```

It seems it's possible to call it though :

```
formals(`function`)
# NULL
`function`(x)
# Error: incorrect number of arguments to "function"
`function`(x,y)
# Error: invalid formal argument list for "function"
`function`(x,y,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
# Error: invalid formal argument list for "function"
```

How (if possible at all) could we define a simple function such as this one:

```
plus <- function(x,y) x+y
```

Here's what I tried:

```
plus <- `function`(x,y,expression(x+y))
# Error: invalid formal argument list for "function"
```

Before you ask, I'm just curious, I don't have any practical use case in mind.

Comment: In the little time playing around/searching, the closest thing I've found to what you're asking that works is calling `function` with `call` as opposed to directly calling the backquoted `` `function` ``.  This is shown in joran's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12983961/5731525).

Comment: maybe you want to read the R internals manual, in particular section 2: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive

Comment: Thanks to Adam and Joran I can do this `plus <- eval(call("function",as.pairlist(alist(x=NULL,y=NULL)),quote(x+y)))` and it works: `plus(3,4)`. I must give a value to `x` and `y` though, and `'function'(as.pairlist(alist(x=NULL,y=NULL)),quote(x+y))` still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank Roland it looks really interesting

Comment: @Artem, definitely very related! Not sure if it's a complete duplicate. What do you think @Moody?

Comment: Sorry to be a buzzkill, Moody. It was a great question, and functional programming is one of my favorite aspects of R, so I love seeing questions in that area.