# Creating a List using formals() - R

Tags: r

Ideally, what I would like to see is that I can create a list that looks like:

```
List[num] <- list(formals(function)= scan("",what="string"))
```

but there is no ideal way to actually get this to play out nicely because `scan` takes as much user input as the user wants and the `formals()` doesn't pass back a string very nicely.

Does anyone know how else I can do this?

Example Code:
function: `mysummary <- function(funcName) { ...}`

`formals(mysummary)` would return `$funcName`

`List[1] <- list(funcName = "string")` is the ideal call where "string" was collected from `scan()`.

Comment: Could you include the desired output? `formals(function)` isn't valid R syntax. Even if it were valid, `list(formals(function) = something)` still wouldn't be.

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to mean in the context of your question.

Comment: I updated it with sample code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make any sense of this at all. It reads to me as though it is the 10th message in a sequence of communications that I haven't seen.

Comment: what is it missing that you can't make sense of? I said 1- what I am trying to achieve and 2- posted sample code. It feels straight forward to me, so please tell me what it is missing

Comment: Maybe someone else will understand it better than I, but it reads to me as though you've said "I'm trying to achieve red carpets in elephant underpants, and my expected output is formal attire modified by green vegetables".

Comment: ...ok, I think I might have a glimmer...

Comment: wild guess (I don't understand the question either): this [knitr-inspired question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9345470/471093) might be similar?

Comment: Maybe you should start from the bigger picture: what are you trying to do? This feels like you're a bit too far down a rabbit hole already.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild ass guess:

```
my_summary <- function(funcName){}
> setNames(list(readline("Value: ")),names(formals(my_summary)))
Value: string
$funcName
[1] "string"
```