# How can I split a string into an alist() in R?

Tags: r, string, list

I'm using the package [`rethinking`](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking), which has a functions `map()` and `map2stan()` to carry out Bayesian estimation (the latter as an interface to `rstan`). `map()` and `map2stan()` take an `alist()` of formulas to define the likelihood and priors, such as:

```
alist(
  height ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
  mu ~ dnorm(178, 20),
  sigma ~ dunif(0, 50)
)
```

which prints as:

```
[[1]]
height ~ dnorm(mu, sigma)

[[2]]
mu ~ dnorm(178, 20)

[[3]]
sigma ~ dunif(0, 50)
```

I'm trying to explore the effects of priors, so I want to be able to pass different sets of means and standard deviations. I can get the priors into a semicolon separated string like:

```
s <- "height ~ dnorm(mu, sigma); mu ~ dnorm(178, 20); sigma ~ dunif(0, 50)"
```

from which I think I should be able to split on `;` and assign to an `alist()`. But I can't figure out this last step.

I have tried variations of:

```
do.call("alist", unlist(strsplit(s,";")))
```

and

```
as.vector(unlist(strsplit(s,";")), mode = "alist")
```

The former fails with `second argument must be a list` and the latter because `as.vector()` doesn't have an "alist" mode.

Maybe the more general question is: how can I get a string into an `alist()`? I have read the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345373/as-alist-character), but I can't figure out how to adapt it for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
lapply(strsplit(s, ";")[[1]], function(x) parse(text = x)[[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

`alist` just returns a list, so you ought to be able to get away with just creating a list of formulae.

```
library(magrittr)
s %>% 
  strsplit("; ", fixed = TRUE) %>% 
  extract2(1) %>% 
  lapply(as.formula)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for simple formulae, which is admittedly what my example is. More complicated ones with more terms like `mu <- a[block] + bHeight * height` fail, because it is trying to evaluate the expression. `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found`. Any thoughts on how to get around that?

Comment: @kmm - If you have a bunch of expressions as strings, you have bigger fish to fry.