# How can I generate an `alist`, when I have the argument names as character vector?

Tags: r

I can generate an `alist` like

```
alist(x = , y = )
```

This can be used to define/override function formals like

```
f <- function() {}
formals(f) <- alist(x = , y = )
formals(f)
$x


$y
```

**How can I generate the same formals, when I only have the argument names as character vector?**

First I tried:

```
v <- c("x", "y")
vector("alist", length(v))
```

but this throws an error:

> Error in vector("alist", length(v)) :    vector: cannot make a vector
>   of mode 'alist'.

Secondly I thought I might construct the expression `x = , y =` with `paste` and `parse`, but this throws another error:

```
string <- paste0(paste0(v, collapse = " = ,"), " = ") 
parse(text = string)
```

> Error in parse(text = string) : :1:5: unexpected ',' 1: x = ,
>           ^

Third I tried using a normal list, but this does not lead to the same thing:

```
l <- vector("list", length(v))
names(l) <- v
l
$x
NULL

$y
NULL
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345373/as-alist-character/9345470)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of `bquote` to create a `list` of `symbols` and name it with the elements in object 'v'

```
l1 <- setNames(rep(list(bquote()), length(v)), v) 
identical(l1, alist(x=, y=))
#[1] TRUE
```